# Creating a Balloon Tip Notification Using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

I am new to powershell!

Thank you to anyone who takes the time out of their day and can kindly help me with this.

NOTES: I AM **NOT** AN ADMINSTRATOR AND MY POWERSHELL IS RUNNING IN CONSTRAINED MODE - IT CANNOT BE CHANGED DUE TO WORK POLICY :D

I have the following code so far:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName  System.Windows.Forms 
$global:balloon = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon 
Get-Member -InputObject  $Global:balloon 
[void](Register-ObjectEvent  -InputObject $balloon  -EventName MouseDoubleClick  -SourceIdentifier IconClicked  -Action {

  #Perform  cleanup actions on balloon tip

  $global:balloon.dispose()

  Unregister-Event  -SourceIdentifier IconClicked

  Remove-Job -Name IconClicked

  Remove-Variable  -Name balloon  -Scope Global

}) 
$path = (Get-Process -id $pid).Path

  $balloon.Icon  = [System.Drawing.Icon]::ExtractAssociatedIcon($path) 
[System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon] | Get-Member -Static -Type Property
$balloon.BalloonTipIcon  = [System.Windows.Forms.ToolTipIcon]::Warning 
$balloon.BalloonTipText  = 'What do you think of this balloon tip?'

  $balloon.BalloonTipTitle  = "Attention  $Env:USERNAME"
$balloon.Visible  = $true 
$balloon.ShowBalloonTip(5000)
```

Sadly this does not work in constrained work - I cannot use the Add-Type function. Is there a code that allows balloon type tip notifications (or anything similar - just need a pop up message) in powershell in constrained mode FOR people with no admin rights.

Error:

```
Cannot invoke method. Method invocation is supported only on core types in this language mode.
```

If this is not possible at all, no worries at all, can someone please clarify this so I can tell my network adminstrator.

Comment: What error do you get if you just run the `Add-Type -AssemblyName  System.Windows.Forms ` command?

Comment: Thank you for your comment :D                                                                            
                                                                                                                            
 Cannot invoke method. Method invocation is supported only on core types in this language mode.

Comment: What is the purpose behind requiring constrained mode? (PowerShell is a program, not a security boundary.)

Comment: honestly I totally agree, it is very frustrating, but there is not much I can do about it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution to this is to get your administrator to add the script as an exception to their policy. This will allow your approved script to run in Full Language mode.

The better solution is for your administrator to allow signed scripts in their policy exceptions and for you to sign your scripts by obtaining a Code Signing certificate from your local CA. On a Windows domain this takes a little setting up but once done is relatively easy to administer.

We block all unsigned scripts on our domain and Admins/Developers are given Code Signing certificates.

Comment: Thank you for your response :D I will be honest with you my network administrator wants to not make any changes at all to the accepted scripts and wants us to stay in constrained mode. The idea is that the above code should work on all pc's (all of them are in constrained mode). If this is not possible at all in constrained mode I shall make my case with the network admin, but I was wondering if there is an alternative notification that would work in constrained mode?

Comment: I don't think that preventing unsigned scripts from running is a security improvement because PowerShell is a _program_, not a security boundary. (Just because a user can run a PowerShell script does not mean that they can do something they couldn't do before. PowerShell scripts don't have magic powers to perform actions outside of a user's security context.)

Comment: There are plenty of situations in any normal corporate environment where a user context is more than sufficient to carry out damaging processes using scripts, especially if they're allowed to be automated/run without supervision. No signing doesn;t prevent, but it does discourage and moves the window to conscious action rather than innocent experimentation.

Comment: But this doesn't stop other forms of automation such as cmd.exe batch files (shell scripts). Any "damage" will be cased by that user account and will show in audit. PowerShell doesn't somehow grant magical powers to bypass security. The security boundary is the user's account (not PowerShell or PowerShell scripts). If your users can cause lots of "damage" by running scripts, they could also do it using  other tools (PowerShell is only one way). I guess I would disagree that you're accomplishing anything really useful in terms of preventing a security issue.